# c# how to build a dynamic query in the where condition

Tags: c#, sql

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(MPRO.OriDes0154) 'QueueCalls' FROM MMProdat.dbo.InstTaWf0154 MPRO WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE MPRO.Estado0154 = 'QUEUED' 
AND F1IdWI02140154<>'VOICEMAIL'
AND F1Camp02930154 = 'Support'
```

please notice that i have `AND F1Camp02930154 = 'Support'`

Now I have a list like this:

```
List<string> compaines = new List<string>();
```

the values in this list should be in this conidtion `AND F1Camp02930154 = 'Support'`

for example if the list is empty, i will get an empty result, but if the list has just one value which is `Support` the query will be

`AND F1Camp02930154 = 'Support'`

but if the list has two vaules which are `Support and Sales` then the query will be

```
AND F1Camp02930154 = 'Support' and `Sales`
```

how to do that please **in c#**

where I already have this:

```
string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(MPRO.OriDes0154) 'QueueCalls' FROM MMProdat.dbo.InstTaWf0154 MPRO WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE MPRO.Estado0154 = 'QUEUED' AND F1IdWI02140154<>'VOICEMAIL'";
```

#### Update 1

After `@ Gordon Linoff` comment

I tried this:

```
List<string> compaines = new List<string>();
            string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(MPRO.OriDes0154) 'QueueCalls' FROM MMProdat.dbo.InstTaWf0154 MPRO WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE MPRO.Estado0154 = 'QUEUED' AND F1IdWI02140154<>'VOICEMAIL' AND F1Camp02930154 IN (";
            for (int i = 0; i < compaines.Count(); i++) {
                queryString += "'" + compaines[i] + "'";
            }
            queryString += ")";
```

Comment: You should use `in` rather than `=` with a bunch of `or`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff great idea, I will try it and update you with the syntax

Comment: If the `compaines` is user supplied you are very vulnerable to SQL injection. Be careful with that.

Comment: @FilipDeVos the compaines is drop down list and I validate it before

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to construct `IN ()` clause, for example :

```
var companies = new List<string>() { "Support", "Sales" };
string inClause = String.Format(" IN ('{0}')", String.Join("', '", companies));
Console.WriteLine("AND F1Camp02930154" + inClause);
//output :
//AND F1Camp02930154 IN ('Support', 'Sales')
```